# What is the relation between $a$ and $b$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a fixed prime number, and $a,b$ two natural numbers satisfying $a>p,b>p$. Assume the following logical equivalence:
$$a\equiv0\mod p\iff b\equiv0\mod p$$
So what is the relation between $a$ and $b$?

Comment: For example if $p=5$ it would just be saying that either each of $a,b$ is divisible by $5$ or else neither is.

Comment: $p$ divides $a$ if and only if $p$ divides $b$ - there is nothing more to say, I wouldn't call this a "relation"

Comment: @Blah: Yes, but I am asking for a real relation between $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would $$k\in\mathbb{Z}$$$$a+kp=b$$ be what you are looking for?

Comment: @ EpicGuy: yes, this what I am looking for.

Comment: That's not exactly correct.  This answer would imply the stronger statement $a \equiv b \pmod p$.  We are only given that $a = 0 \iff b = 0 \pmod p$.  We could easily have $(a, b, p) = (1, 3, 5)$ satisfying the original question, but not this answer.

Comment: @Macavity thanks for pointing that out. Is there any answer to this then?

Comment: @  EpicGuy: But, if $a+kp=b$
    $$b≡0(mod(p))⇒a≡0(mod(p))$$
    $$a≡0(mod(p))⇒b=a+kp≡0(mod(p))$$ and maybe we can take $a>p$ and $b>p$.

Comment: I am not sure if you can find a more concise statement which is accurate, other than $p \mid a \iff p \mid b$.  This is because there is no linear or other "relation" between $a, b$.  For e.g. if $p=5$, all of the following ordered pairs are also allowed $(a, b) = (6, 7), (6, 8), (7, 7), (7, 8)$ etc. the problem is that if $p \not \mid a$, then we cannot have $p \mid b$, but there is no other restriction on $b$, it can be anything other than a multiple of $p$.

Comment: We could specify an integer less than p and somehow add it to $a$ to get $b$?

Comment: @  Macavity: Maybe I can think on the condition: $k>p$

Comment: What we need is that $a\not\mid p\Rightarrow b\not\mid p$?

Answer (score 1):

A relation is a subset $R \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ and in your case you cannot write down such a thing
$$
R := \{(a,b)\in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} | a>p, b>p, ...???? \}
$$
The problem is that *a logical equivalence*
$$
p | a \Leftrightarrow p|b
$$
is not a property of a pair of numbers.

Comment: @ Blah: I do not mean this type of relations, I mean an algebraic relation.